# How to use google code-prettify to show diff

Tags: google-code-prettify

I have a an application that can browse out code tree and can show individual source code that are nicely highlighted using google code google code-prettify

I want to add a feature that shows diff between version. I have the changes in git-diff format

my question is: it the google code prettify supports diff? are thre any code examples for this?

Comment: fyi, since I wrote this question, I realized google code prettify is very slow and switched to self written module

Comment: You cant do it for now: https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/559